# How can I correct spelling errors in MySQL column using a query?

Tags: php, mysql

I am new with mysql so I have inserted into a table column about 2000 records and some of them have spelling errors.

Can I use

```
update Names set City = replace(City, "%New Yorks%", "New York");
```

but with an IF condition inside replace to check IF word has a particular character do the replace.

In several words I want to change the i with e and the a with o can I do them all together?

Thank you

Comment: You should be more specific and actually say _what_ condition you want to apply.

Answer (score 2):

Use Single quotes instead of double quotes and lose the `%`

```
update Names set City = replace(City, 'New Yorks', 'New York');
```

Comment: Perfect Answer. Saved Time. Thank You